# How to decompress a gzip request PHP/Lumen/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, http-post, gzip, lumen

I am receiving requests from a third party that are gzip encoded text (~1mb so it makes sense)

My test route:

```
$router->post(
    'testgzip',
    function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        $decompressed = null;
        if ($request->header('content-encoding') === 'gzip') {
            $decompressed = gzinflate($request->getContent());
        }

        return [
            'body' => $decompressed ?? $request->getContent(),
        ];
    }
);
```

My test file **test.txt**

```
hello world!
```

My sanity check:

```
curl --data-binary @test.txt -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -X POST http://localhost:8000/testgzip 
{"body":"hello world!"}
```

To compress it I run the command
`gzip test.txt`

My curl:

```
curl --data-binary @test.txt.gz -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" -X POST http://localhost:8000/testgzip
```

---

Which triggers a

## gzinflate(): data error

I also tried gzuncompress which triggers

## gzuncompress(): data error

What am I doing wrong? How can I decompress a gzip request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For gzipped content you need to use `gzdecode()`.

```php
$decompressed = gzdecode($request->getContent());
```

This is built-in on PHP.

gzinflate() deals with deflated (not gzipped) and gzuncompress() with compresed (not gzipped) strings.

Docs:

- [gzinflate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php)
- [gzuncompress](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php)
- [gzdecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php)

Comment: Thanks! those terms seem so interchangeable to me, especially since all the functions start with gz

Comment: @Moak I still get `data error` even with gzdecode()

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
gzuncompress(base64_decode($request->getContent()));
```